# How to use onchange function with dropdown and a total sum in HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I'm currently stuck at a shopping cart like HTML site in which the items get created dynamically. I want the sum of a single item and the total sum to refresh when the dropdown gets select to a certain value. I tried this with a onchange function but this didn't work. What am I doing wrong and is there a way to refresh the sums at all?

The JavaScript code is the following:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        console.log("BEREIT ZUM SOP");
        var sum = 0;

        // artikel in von session holen über sbservice
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/HandyHammer/rest/shoppingbasket",
                method: "GET",
                dataType: "json" 
            })
            .done(function(responseData) {
                console.log(responseData);
                for(var i=0;i<responseData.length;i++){
                    var data1=responseData[i];
                    console.log("sarajevo");
                    console.log("istanbul");
                    console.log(data1);
                var prc= data1.price;
                sum = sum + prc;  //addiere summe
                console.log(sum);
                var tmp = '<tr> <td id="warenid">'+data1.id+'</td> <td id="Bezeichnung">'+data1.title+'</td>  <td id="preis">'+prc+'€</td> <td><select id="menge" name="maximum10">';
                tmp += '<option value="1">1</option> <option value="2">2</option> <option value="3">3</option> <option value="4">4</option>';
                tmp += '<option value="5">5</option> <option value="6">6</option> <option value="7">7</option> <option value="8">8</option> <option value="9">9</option> <option value="10">10</option>';
                tmp += '</select></td><td id="summe">'+prc+'</td> <td><a id="removeBestellung" class="btn1" type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> </td>'; //removebestellung kommt später DONT FORGET
                tmp += '</tr>';
                $("#upper").after(tmp);
                }





            var select = document.getElementById("menge");      
               select.onchange = function() {
                   var answer = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
                   console.log("Wert der Dropdown   "+answer);
                  var summe = document.getElementById("summe").innerHTML;
                  console.log("wert der SUMME Yeet    " + summe*answer);
                  var oldval = summe;
                  var newval = summe*answer;
                  var diff = newval - oldval;
                  document.getElementById("summe").innerHTML = newval;
               }

                var onsumme = document.getElementById("summe");
                console.log("sum 1  " + sum);
                console.log("summe element  " + onsumme);
                    onsumme.onchange = function() {
                        console.log("diff variable   " + diff);
                    sum += diff;
                    console.log("sum funktion  " + sum);
                    $(".total").append(sum+"€");
                    }

            })
            .fail(function( errorResponse, statusText, error ) {    // fehlerfall
                alert(errorResponse.responseText);
            });


                /*  $("#menge").change(function(){
                      console.log("change funktion aufgerufen  " + sum);
                     var select = document.getElementById("menge");
                     var answer = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
                     console.log(answer);
                     var x = document.getElementById("sume").textContent;
                     document.getElementById('summe').textContent = x * answer ;
                  }); */
    });
    </script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: please post only code that describes your problem not whole the page.

Comment: done. Only the JavaScript code now

Comment: Any reason you're using jQuery on the top and not the bottom code?

Comment: well i'm a newbie at programming so don't judge please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the below Select onChange Jquery event, you can get the value wheneven you change the select option value.

```
 $( "select" ).change(function() {
    selectedValue= parseInt$(this).val());
    selectedValue + (X number);
    alert( selectedValue + (X number));
  });
```

in the above script, selected value will be stored in the **selectedValue** variable so you can add  the value with that same variable.

Link for your reference: https://jsfiddle.net/5dbx80f3/6/

Answer (score 0):

You are having problem because the type of 'summe' isnt integer. you can convert it into integer by using

```
var summe = parseInt(document.getElementById("summe").innerHTML);
```